# Projection to extract date from ObjectID

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to do something like this:

```
db.users.find({}, {name: 1, 'timestampFrom(_id)': 1})
```

So that I can see creation timestamps against usernames

Is there a way of extracting the timestamp from the ObjectID in a projection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at `ObjectId.getTimestamp()` ([Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp)).

You can also `map` ([Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/)) this function with your query.

```
db.users.find({}, {name: 1, _id : 1}).map(function(u) { return {name: u.name, created: u._id.getTimestamp() } });
```

Returns a list with custom `user` objects having the `name` and new `created` property.

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Jack",
        "created" : ISODate("2014-01-03T21:04:19Z")
    },
    {
        "name" : John,
        "created" : ISODate("2014-01-07T18:12:50Z")
    }
]
```